# Post shipment data to a remote server

Tags: api, shipment

I'm trying to send shipping info to a remote server. How I can post this JSON data when saving a tracking number on magento backend?

```
<?php
    $data = array(
        "apiKey" => "MYAPI",

        "pushTrack" => array(
            array(
                "trackingNumber" => "1Z0V5V416840696735",
                "courier" => "UPS",
                "shipDate" => "2014-08-01"
                ), //minimun required fields example

            array(
                "trackingNumber" => "1Z0V5V416840696736",
                "courier" => "UPS", "shipDate" => "2014-08-02",
                "reference" => "ord. # 1674",
                "orderDate" => "2014-07-30",
                "name" => "NAME",
                "street" => "STREET",
                "city" => "CITY",
                "ZIP" => "12345",
                "state" => "AA",
                "country" => "IT",
                "email" => "name@domain.ext",
                "telephone" => "02342522",
                "agent" => "007@company.ext",
                "amount" => "150,00",
                "pod" => "1",
                "shipping" => "8,00",
                "custom1" => "valore custom 1",
                "custom2" => "valore custom 2",
                "custom3" => "valore custom 3",
                "custom3" => "valore custom 3",
                "note" => "This is a note",
                "deliveryDate" => "2014-07-31",
                "tag" => "customer1"
            )
        )

    );

    $data_string = json_encode($data);

    $ch = curl_init('REMOTEURL');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;
    ?>
```

Comment: ADD: I can get ALL useful data with this sql query

SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_shipment_track` as s, `sales_flat_order` as o 
WHERE s.order_id = o.entity_id
AND s.created_at > '2015-10-01'

but I don't know how to parse result in my array format

Comment: Please clarify what exactly is your problem. Your POST does not work or you need to reformat data that you get from DB to necessary format?